# Docker custom user with permission to run apache

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am working on Docker image for PHP application. I am using `php:7.2-apache` base image (`FROM php:7.2-apache`).

Also I want to use custom user inside my container (I think it is more secure):

```
...
RUN groupadd -g 999 dev && useradd -r -u 999 -g devuser devuser && \
    chown -R devuser:devuser $PWD && \
    chown -R devuser:devuser /var/www/html/ && \
    mkdir -p  /home/devuser/.npm && \
    chown -R devuser:devuser /home/devuser/.npm
USER devuser
...
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

After I added the custom user described above - I started to get permission errors for Apache:

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address :80                                                                                                                                           
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

What is the best way to use a custom user (not root) for docker images and allow them to run specific commands? How it is possible to fix Apache run?

Comment: Ports below 1024 are privileged and you need to be superuser to bind to them. To fix it, I'd listen on an unprivilged port, like 8080, instead. It shouldn't matter, since you'll map the port to a host port using docker.